# Prevent users from supplying emails

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, new-users, email

Occasionally, I will come across a post (either a question or an answer) where, at the end of their code, something like this will be there:

> If you have any more questions, you can contact me at `name@email.com`.

I believe there should be a pop-up and a block preventing the user from posting that question when an email is detect somewhere in the post.

Having emails in posts is bad because it encourages other users to continue a discussion outside of SE, which can lead to unconnected information (for example, a tip in an answer that is a response to something said in an email), and it prevents future users from seeing all the information that the OP has to offer.

Comment: Is that really such a big problem that it warrants a feature?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's not *that big* of a problem, but it's not *that complicated* of a solution either.

Comment: Can you guarantee that there is no programming language in the world that would have valid syntax that would trip an email-matching regex? Granted, that is perhaps unlikely, but... can you further guarantee that any code with an example/placeholder email (e.g. `test@example.org`) isn't worth posting? This isn't as uncomplicated as you may think.

Comment: I think one of the bots in [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) complains if there's a post anywhere on the network with an email in it.

Comment: @Shokhet Not quite; it [excludes several sites](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py#L216) from this check, and also ignores emails appearing in code blocks (and emails with @example...). There are still some false positives: people discussing,  e.g., customer databases, talk about storing and retrieving emails quite a bit.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks for clarifying that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I agree e-mail addresses should not be posted. However, such a filter would undoubtedly hit a lot of innocent posts as well.

I do not dare to guess how many posts there are on SO alone about matching e-mail addresses. Communicating about such questions and answers is going to get tough if you forbid placing e-mail addresses altogether, even the obviously fake ones.

Another problem is it won't be able to detect `account[at]domain[dot]tld` and all other imaginable variants. Checking whether an e-mail address is valid is hard. Checking whether any part of a post is a valid, non-bogus e-mail address even harder.

We could do a warning (but who reads those nowadays?), but a block would definitely create more problems than it would solve.

Comment: There are also legitimate reasons for writing emails in posts, e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/a/45044

Comment: There are also [LBRY](https://lbry.com/) URLs, e.g. `https://odysee.com/@eevblog:7` (though they seem to be covered (no false positives)).